# tch-rs , when compile with tokenizers library , encounter static libcpmt.lib and dynamic msvcprt.lib conflict link error

Tags: rust, huggingface-transformers, rust-cargo, huggingface-tokenizers

when compile with tokenizers library , encounter static libcpmt.lib and dynamic  msvcprt.lib conflict link error.
My program use tokenizers 0.15.0 and tch-rs 0.14.0 , such as below:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use tokenizers::Tokenizer;
use tch;
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    //load model
    let model_file = "anyhow_to_the_model_path";
    let model =tch::CModule::load(model_file)?;  
    println!("model loaded");     
   Ok(())
    
}
```

The cargo reports: "error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1169"

=note:libtorch_sys-14beaa7f5e22ac1d.rlib(torch_api.o) : error LNK2038:  detect “RuntimeLibrary” non-match value “MD_DynamicRelease” non-match value “MT_StaticRelease”(libesaxx_rs-0ddd131668a89c52.rlib(esaxx.o) ).

I wonder how I can fix this error. My dependencies are  torch-rs 0.14 and tokenziers 0.15.

I tried set env: LIBTORCH_STATIC=1, but it failed .

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "ts-infer"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
publish = ["rsproxy"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tch = "0.14.0"
anyhow = "1.0"
tokenizers = "0.15.1"
```

and rustup show:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

And more:

1. tokenizers package cargo.toml:
   https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/main/tokenizers/Cargo.toml
2. tch-rs Cargo.toml:
   https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs/blob/main/Cargo.toml

Comment: The problem isn't with your Rust code, but with the environment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77985667/edit) your question to add the contents of your `Cargo.toml` and `build.rs` if you have one. Also, can you add the output of `rustup show`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The esaxx-rs package included by tokenizers use static link to crt. I moidfy the build.rs of esaxx-rs and delete the static link code